# How to call a function via onChange of a TextField Select type from the MaterialUI package

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I'm trying to make the onChange of a Select type JTextField, from the MaterialUI package, to trigger a function.

I created the following component called Select, it is a TextField of type select:

```
import React from 'react';
import { TextField, MenuItem, TextFieldProps } from '@material-ui/core';
import { useField, useFormikContext } from 'formik';

export type Option = {
  id: number;
  name: string;
};

type ITextFieldProps = TextFieldProps & {
  name: string;
  options: Option[];
};

const SelectWrapper: React.FC<ITextFieldProps> = ({
  name,
  options,
  ...otherProps
}) => {
  const { setFieldValue } = useFormikContext();
  const [field, meta] = useField(name);

  const handleChange = (evt: React.ChangeEvent<any>) => {
    const { value } = evt.target;
    setFieldValue(name, value);
  };

  const configSelect = {
    ...field,
    ...otherProps,
    select: true,
    fullWidth: true,
    onChange: handleChange,
    error: false,
    helperText: '',
  };

  if (meta && meta.touched && meta.error) {
    configSelect.error = true;
    configSelect.helperText = meta.error;
  }

  return (
    <TextField variant="outlined" {...configSelect}>
      {options.map(opt => {
        return (
          <MenuItem key={opt.id} value={opt.id}>
            {opt.name}
          </MenuItem>
        );
      })}
    </TextField>
  );
};

export default SelectWrapper;
```

In another file, I imported this component, I would like when I change the selection, call a certain function. I did it as follows, however, the function is not triggered.

```
<Select
    name="company"
    label="Selecione uma Empresa"
    options={companies}
    size="small"
    onChange={e => getUnits(e)}
/>
```

Edit: if I use onBlur, it works. Only with onChange does not work.

**Function:**

```
  const getUnits = useCallback(e => {
    alert('test');
    console.log(e.target.value);
  }, []);
```

In the link below there is a gist with the contents of the file where I call the select component and the function.
https://gist.github.com/fredarend/1bd35d6d613ad547f3b6805f545d5ef4

Comment: In `<Select>`, it looks like you set `onChange` to `handleChange` and never call the `onChange`that was passed in as a prop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to dereference the `onChange` property from the `ITextFieldProps` as follows ...

```
const SelectWrapper: React.FC<ITextFieldProps> = ({
  name,
  options,
  onChange,
  ...otherProps
})
```

Then you need to call it in your own event handler ...

FWIW, I would get rid of the `const { setFieldValue } = useFormikContext();` statement and use the helper on the `useField` hook instead. You can use the `setValue` method of the helper to assign the value for that specific field without needing a form reference. I would then call `setTouched` for the field value for good measure. (Although it's not 'technically' needed.)

```
  const [field, meta, helper] = useField(name);
```

... and then

```
  const handleChange = (evt: React.ChangeEvent<any>) => {
    const { value } = evt.target;
    helper.setValue(value);

    setTimeout(() => fieldHelper.setTouched(true));

    if (onChange) onChange(value);
  };

  const configSelect = {
    ...field,
    ...otherProps,
    select: true,
    fullWidth: true,
    onChange: handleChange,
    error: false,
    helperText: '',
  };
```